# How to change Firebase Authentication password through Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I can create users in Firebase using email and password.But there's now way I can change the password of that user using database. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

[Update User Password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/auth/user#classfirebase_1_1auth_1_1_user_1a53aa1dc77b04ddee678c8163142b6ee0) (must be authenticated).